# Global and local variables in R

Tags: r

I am a newbie for R, and I am quite confused with the usage of local and global variables in R.

I read some posts on the internet that say if I use `=` or `<-` I will assign the variable in the current environment, and with `<<-` I can access a global variable when inside a function.

However, as I remember in C++ local variables arise whenever you declare a variable inside brackets `{}`, so I'm wondering if this is the same for R? Or is it just for *functions* in R that we have the concept of local variables.

I did a little experiment, which seems to suggest that only brackets are not enough, am I getting anything wrong?

```
{
   x=matrix(1:10,2,5)
}
print(x[2,2])
[1] 4
```

Comment: Some code to run in addition to these answers: `globalenv(); globalenv() %>% parent.env; globalenv() %>% parent.env %>% parent.env`, …

Comment: @isomorphismes, `Error: could not find function "%>%"` . Is that another form of assignment?

Comment: Relevant thread on R-help: [**What does the "<<-" operator mean?**](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/What-does-the-quot-lt-lt-quot-operator-mean-td3466657.html).

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Hi, sorry for not responding sooner! That is from `require(magrittr)`. It's a way of applying functions on the right (`x | f1 | f2 | f3`) instead of on the left (`f3( f2( f1( x ) ) )`).

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Variables declared inside a function are local to that function. For instance:

```
foo <- function() {
    bar <- 1
}
foo()
bar
```

gives the following error: `Error: object 'bar' not found`.

If you want to make `bar` a global variable, you should do:

```
foo <- function() {
    bar <<- 1
}
foo()
bar
```

In this case `bar` is accessible from outside the function.

However, unlike C, C++ or many other languages, brackets do not determine the scope of variables. For instance, in the following code snippet:

```
if (x > 10) {
    y <- 0
}
else {
    y <- 1
}
```

`y` remains accessible after the `if-else` statement.

As you well say, you can also create nested environments. You can have a look at these two links for understanding how to use them:

1. http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/environment.html
2. http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html

Here you have a small example:

```
test.env <- new.env()

assign('var', 100, envir=test.env)
# or simply
test.env$var <- 100

get('var') # var cannot be found since it is not defined in this environment
get('var', envir=test.env) # now it can be found
```

Answer (score 157):

`<-` does assignment in the current environment.

When you're inside a function R creates a new environment for you.  By default it includes everything from the environment in which it was created so you can use those variables as well but anything new you create will not get written to the global environment.

In most cases `<<-` will assign to variables already in the global environment or create a variable in the global environment even if you're inside a function.  However, it isn't quite as straightforward as that.  What it does is checks the parent environment for a variable with the name of interest.  If it doesn't find it in your parent environment it goes to the parent of the parent environment (at the time the function was created) and looks there.  It continues upward to the global environment and if it isn't found in the global environment it will assign the variable in the global environment.

This might illustrate what is going on.

```
bar <- "global"
foo <- function(){
    bar <- "in foo"
    baz <- function(){
        bar <- "in baz - before <<-"
        bar <<- "in baz - after <<-"
        print(bar)
    }
    print(bar)
    baz()
    print(bar)
}
> bar
[1] "global"
> foo()
[1] "in foo"
[1] "in baz - before <<-"
[1] "in baz - after <<-"
> bar
[1] "global"
```

The first time we print bar we haven't called `foo` yet so it should still be global - this makes sense.  The second time we print it's inside of `foo` before calling `baz` so the value "in foo" makes sense.  The following is where we see what `<<-` is actually doing.  The next value printed is "in baz - before <<-" even though the print statement comes after the `<<-`.  This is because `<<-` doesn't look in the current environment (unless you're in the global environment in which case `<<-` acts like `<-`). So inside of `baz` the value of bar stays as "in baz - before <<-". Once we call `baz` the copy of bar inside of `foo` gets changed to "in baz" but as we can see the global `bar` is unchanged. This is because the copy of `bar` that is defined inside of `foo` is in the parent environment when we created `baz` so this is the first copy of `bar` that `<<-` sees and thus the copy it assigns to.  So `<<-` isn't just directly assigning to the global environment.

`<<-` is tricky and I wouldn't recommend using it if you can avoid it.  If you really want to assign to the global environment you can use the assign function and tell it explicitly that you want to assign globally.

Now I change the `<<-` to an assign statement and we can see what effect that has:

```
bar <- "global"
foo <- function(){
    bar <- "in foo"   
    baz <- function(){
        assign("bar", "in baz", envir = .GlobalEnv)
    }
    print(bar)
    baz()
    print(bar)
}
bar
#[1] "global"
foo()
#[1] "in foo"
#[1] "in foo"
bar
#[1] "in baz"
```

So both times we print bar inside of `foo` the value is "in foo" even after calling `baz`.  This is because `assign` never even considered the copy of `bar` inside of foo because we told it exactly where to look.  However, this time the value of bar in the global environment was changed because we explicitly assigned there.

Now you also asked about creating local variables and you can do that fairly easily as well without creating a function...  We just need to use the `local` function.

```
bar <- "global"
# local will create a new environment for us to play in
local({
    bar <- "local"
    print(bar)
})
#[1] "local"
bar
#[1] "global"
```

Comment: Can I configure a function in a way that the environment inside it is the same as the outside? meaning any variable created with <- will be available outside it

Comment: Kind of yes but it's a terrible idea. I'm not going to help you with that because it's that bad. It's much better to return the results and let the user decide how to use them.

Answer (score 5):

A bit more along the same lines

```
attrs <- {}

attrs.a <- 1

f <- function(d) {
    attrs.a <- d
}

f(20)
print(attrs.a)
```

will print "1"

```
attrs <- {}

attrs.a <- 1

f <- function(d) {
   attrs.a <<- d
}

f(20)
print(attrs.a)
```

Will print "20"