# How to add a new member to the list in a function in R

Tags: r

I want to add a new member to the list. When I do it as follows. But when I want to do it in a function, nothing changes..

```
> a = list( x=4, y=2)
> a
$x
[1] 4

$y
[1] 2

> a$c = 7
> a
$x
[1] 4

$y
[1] 2

$c
[1] 7
```

Using a function...

```
> addNew(a)
> a
$x
[1] 4

$y
[1] 2
```

The function is:

```
addNew = function(list){
  list$c = 7
}
```

Maybe it is kinda problem like pointers in c, but how can solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return and assign the modified list:

```
a <- list(x=4, y=2)
addNew <- function(l) {
  l$c <- 7
  return(l)
}
a <- addNew(a)
```

EDIT: As @mitra mentioned you could use `<<-`:

```
a <- list(x=4, y=2)
addNew <- function() {
  a$c <<- 7
}
```

But that changes the typical behaviour of a function in R. Most user didn't expect that a function has side effects like changing the global environment.

Please read Patrick Burns' [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) (p. 35):

> If you think you need <<- , think again. If on reflection you still think you
>   need <<- , think again. Only when your boss turns red with anger over you
>   not doing anything should you temporarily give in to the temptation. There
>   have been proposals (no more than half-joking) to eliminate <<- from the
>   language. That would not eliminate global assignments, merely force you to use
>   the assign function to achieve them.

Comment: That's true! But is there any other way to do it? I may want to modify more than one list in the function..

Comment: You could return a list of lists ;).

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the difference between local and global variables:

[Global and local variables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904124/global-and-local-variables-in-r)

If you define a variable inside a function, it is temporary and belongs to the function only.

check this:

```
list$c<<-7
```

Comment: I tried a global variable also, it wasn't changed. Is there any special way to defien global variable in R?

Comment: list$c <<- 7 is works. Thanks! But you should write the actual variable name as in global, not work via parameter name..