# How do I empty a list in R?

Tags: r, list, empty-list

I have a file with an R program. I load it interactively on R and then I call the main function. During the execution I fill up some global lists but when I run the main function again I want those lists to be empty. How can I empty a filled up list? I tried doing

```
list <- NULL
```

after execution but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you give some more context? Maybe the code for the entire function? When I run `list <- c("a", "b", "c")` and `list <- NULL`
this seems to empty the list.

Comment: Maybe you want `list <- list()` in order to add elements later via `list[[i]] <- ...`. (BTW, as you can see, the name is poorly chosen).

Comment: It should be noted that relying on globals isn't best practice.  If you explain what you're doing we can probably find a better way...

Comment: @Dason Yeah I know but I needed to do a quick program and I'm not really familiar with R so I used global variables for simplicity. I was programming a hanged man game so I needed global lists for the letters chosen by the player to compare them with the word chosen by the executioner.

Comment: So is this an exercise to learn R?  If so I would think that taking the extra time to learn how to do things 'the R way' would be more beneficial than just plowing through relying on bad practice.

Comment: Not really is for a friend who needs to do some experiments but knows nothing about programming. I can't spend too much on this though since I need to do stuff of my own that's why is kind of sloppy but functional... if I have time later I'll fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are setting them globally, you probably need `list <<- NULL`, because the `<<-` operator assigns global variables.

#### Edit, per @Dason's comment:

The `<<-` operator can in some circumstances fail to change the value of a variable in all possible environments. For that reason, it is better to use

```
assign("list", NULL, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: What does the <<- signify?

Comment: As I explain in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10904810/1003565) using `<<-` isn't quite as straightforward as you might expect.  If you *absolutely* know you want it to be a global assignment then you're safer using `assign`

Comment: Can i do assign("list", NULL, envir = .GlobalEnv) then??

Comment: @Atirag: You could, but it is considered poor programming practice to create data objects that are named exactly as a class name. Preferred would be `assign("myList", NULL, envir = .GlobalEnv)`