# Returning and accessing objects from functions in R

Tags: r, function, variables

I wrote a function in R that returns a list composed of two variables.  The function works correctly in that the correct values are returned.  The problem, however, is that I can't then access the list for further processing.  The code is this:

```
grinder <- function(x) {

if(x == "BID") {
miles <- 18.4 * n.row
tolls <- 1.8 * n.row

} else if(x == "SPR") {
miles <- 10.8 * n.row
tolls <- 0

} else if (x == "BRI") {
miles <- 3.8 * n.row
tolls <- 0

} else if (x == "GOO") {
miles <- 66.2 * n.row
tolls <- 1.8 * n.row

} else if (x == "MIL") {
miles <- 108
tolls <- 0

} else if (x == "SMH") {
miles <- 94.6 * n.row
tolls <- 2 * n.row

}

mil.tol <- list(miles,tolls)
return(mil.tol)

}

grinder(x)
```

The correct values are returned, but I can't then access mil.tol to do anything with those values.  Nor can I get correct values for miles or tolls.  The console returns this:

```
> mil.tol
Error: object 'mil.tol' not found
> miles
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: mil.tol <- grinder(x)  and then access it

Comment: You should expect `grinder` to work like any normal R function. This means it doesn't just "create" objects for you, you assign the result to an object. If you run a linear model `lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)` it would be **terrible** if that created an object in your workspace called "model" - you couldn't ever work with more than one model at a time. Just like you're used to naming and assigning your models `mod1 <- lm(...)`, you need to name and assign the output of your function: `mil.tol <- grinder(x)`

Answer (score 0):

`miles`, `tolls` and `mil.tol` are all local to the function and are not returned, but you can assign the output of the function (i.e. from the `return()`) like below to mil.tol:

```
mil.tol <- grinder(x)
```

Would recommend also reading this SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904124/global-and-local-variables-in-r)