# How is scoping done in R

Tags: c, r, scope, nested

Both `R` and `C` have lexical scope. So assuming that global scope is empty, in `C` the following code would not work :

```
int aux(int arg) {
   if (arg > 0) {
      int result = 1;
   } else {
      int result = 0;
   }
   return result;
 }
```

While in `R` the following code :

```
aux <- function(arg) {
   if (arg > 0) {
      result = 1
   } else {
      result = 0
   }
   return(result)
 }
```

Works properly. Can someone tell me what is the difference in scoping between `R` and `C` which makes these two functions behave differently?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904124/global-and-local-variables-in-r) should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R, the expression after the `if` condition is evaluated in the enclosing environment:

```
if (TRUE) environment()
#<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

(Surprisingly, I couldn't find documentation regarding this.)

---

You can change that by using `local`:

```
aux <- function(arg) {
  if (arg > 0) {
    local({result <- 1})
  } else {
    local({result <- 0})
  }
  return(result)
}

aux(1)
#Error in aux(1) : object 'result' not found
```