# <<- not working - R - call object from outside function

Tags: r, function, dplyr, global-variables

I've looked through the forums here and figure out that `<<-` assign a variable inside a function to a global variable (to be accessible outside the function).

I've done so below, but to no avail - any thoughts?

```
> Billeddata_import <- function(burl="C:\\Users\\mcantwell\\Desktop\\Projects\\M & V Analysis\\Final_Bills.csv"){
+         billeddata<-read.csv(burl,header=TRUE, sep=",",stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
+             mutate(Usage=as.numeric(Usage)) %>%
+                 #Service.Begin.Date=as.Date(Service.Begin.Date,format='%m/%d/%Y'),
+                  #Service.End.Date=as.Date(Service.End.Date,format='%m/%d/%Y')) %>%
+        
+         filter(UOM=="Kw",
+                !is.na(Usage),
+                Service.Description %in% c("Demand","Demand On Peak", "Demand Off Peak", "Dmd Partial Pk")) %>%
+         group_by(Location..,Service.Begin.Date,Service.End.Date) %>%
+         summarise(monthly_peak=max(Usage))
+         out<<-billdata
+     }
> out
Error: object 'out' not found
>
```

The object `billdata` is a data table that I cleaned up in `Billeddata_import()`, and I'm hoping to use  it in later functions.

Running the function alone yields:

```
> Billeddata_import()
Error in Billeddata_import() : object 'billdata' not found
```

without the `out<<-billdata` line, `Billeddata_import()` runs fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***NOTE:*** Using `<<-` is bad practice. You can read this **[thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904124/global-and-local-variables-in-r/10904810#10904810)** to know more about this.

You need to run the function. Here, you just define it. Take one step further and run it before looking for `out`.

Since we do not have your data, look at the example below;

```
#This is an example:
myfun <- function(xdat=df) {
  billeddata <- xdat %>% select(-var3) %>% 
                        filter(var1=="treatment5")

  out<<-billeddata
  }

 myfun(df) #You need to run the function!!!
 out

#         var1    var2       value 
# 1 treatment5 group_2 0.005349631 
# 2 treatment5 group_2 0.005349631 
# 3 treatment5 group_1 0.005349631
```

***Data:***

```
df <- structure(list(var1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
      3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("treatment1", "treatment2", 
      "treatment3", "treatment4", "treatment5"), class = "factor"), 
      var2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
      2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("group_1", "group_2"), class = "factor"), 
      var3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
      2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("C8.0", "C8.1", "C8.2"), class = "factor"), 
      value = c(0.010056478, 0.009382918, 0.003014983, 0.005349631, 
      0.005349631, 0.010056478, 0.009382918, 0.003014983, 0.005349631, 
      0.005349631, 0.010056478, 0.009382918, 0.003014983, 0.005349631, 
      0.005349631)), .Names = c("var1", "var2", "var3", "value"
  ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

***P.S.***

Even if you want to use `return(out)` you still need to run the function after defining it.

Moreover, using `return()` will not add a variable to your global. You need to assign it while calling the function, like this:

```
out <- myfun(df)
```

Comment: I think you need to be stronger in your answer about discouraging use of `<<-` here. It is bad practice and returning the value is the better way

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `return(out)` as the last line in your function, and then call your function every time you need to access your variable.

Comment: @sweeI tried that and couldn't access the columns.

Comment: This is actually not necessary--you don't need to use the return function to return an object at the end of a function. The `return(out)` does the same thing as `out` except it also exits the function.