# Global vs Local within userdefined function

Tags: r, dataframe

I am making changes to a global dataframe within my user defined function. The dataframe is created outside of the function.

However, my changes to the dataframe are not visible outside of the function. Only if I use a return option, I end up with the dataframe.

Is there a way to change this?

Comment: That's the way functional programming should work.

Comment: You can use the double arrow to assign outside the function, `<<-`. But reread @Gregor 's comment.

Comment: Yes there is a way to do it. But you really shouldn't.

Comment: Alright alright, I will take a different approach then. I realized that this is going to be error prone down the line. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904124/global-and-local-variables-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you *should* do "call by reference" functionality in R is one question (addressed in the comments - generally the answer is no).

However, you asked *whether* you can do it. The answer is *yes*, you *can* modify your global dataframe in the local scope of your function. Here is how you do it: 1) Use `eval.parent()` (set the evaluation scope to the calling scope, which, presumably, is the global scope) and 2) `substitute()` (to replace the variable reference instead of destroying one and creating a new one).

Here's an example:

```
> attach(mtcars)
> my_cars <- mtcars[mpg,] #not sorted
> pointless_sort <- function() {
+     eval.parent(substitute(my_cars<-mtcars[order(mpg),]))
+ }
> pointless_sort()
> #here the global my_cars is ordered/sorted by mpg
```

Important points: 1) You *can* do it; 2) Good programming generally means *not* doing it (but we've all been lazy, wanted a convenient way to split up code). Now you have the power.

> "With Great Power Comes Great Responsibility."

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for demonstrating this. I will try to avoid the approach but keep this in the back of my head (just in case).

Comment: In honesty, it depends on the situation. Purists will say to never do it. If it's not production or maintained code, just something you do once, what's the difference?

Comment: Agreed. For me as a beginner it is probably helpful though to adhere to 'robust' programming principles early on.