# Force evaluation of R list assignment in recursive call

Tags: r, recursion, lazy-evaluation

I have a list `mylist` which gets populated in a recursive function -- however, when accessing the elements *later* within the recursion, they are still NULL.

A minimal example:

```
mylist = vector("list",5)

myf = function(x){
    if(x==1){
        mylist[[x]] = "hi"
        message("Set value at position ",x," to ",mylist[[x]])
        force(mylist[[x]] = "hi")
    }
    else{
        mylist[[x]] = "hi"
        message("Set value at position ",x," to ",mylist[[x]])
        myf(x-1)
        message("Value at position ",x-1, " is ",mylist[[x-1]])
    }
}
```

Which yields

```
Set value at position 4 to hi
Set value at position 3 to hi
Set value at position 2 to hi
Set value at position 1 to hi
Value at position 1 is 
Value at position 2 is 
Value at position 3 is
```

You can see that I tried force(...) but without success.

On the discussion of global vs local variable, it has been suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904124/global-and-local-variables-in-r) to use `<<-` instead of the `=` assignment symbol to set the global variable. However, this does not help here. It has been further recommended in answers to that post to use `assign(...)` but it looks to me as if that would not work for lists.

Comment: `force` is not intended to be used in that way. It is only a trivial function thats return his argument, only to make it clear that it is evaluated (writing force(x) is the same that writing x alone in a line).
In fact, your code is not valid code.

Comment: My first attempt was to use`force(mylist[[x]])`, but that does not work either unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

`assign` will allow you to accomplish your goal. The `<<-` operator would work too.

```r
mylist <- vector("list", 5)

myf <- function(x){ 
  if (x == 1) {
    mylist[[ x ]] = "hi" # <-- local assignment
    message("Set value at position ", x, " to ", mylist[[ x ]]) # local
    mylist[[ x ]] = "hi" # <-- local assignment
    assign('mylist', mylist, envir = parent.frame())  # <-- assign to mylist in parent environment
    tmp <- get('mylist', envir = parent.frame())
    message('mylist in parent envirnonment: ')
    print(tmp)
  }
  else {
    mylist[[ x ]] = "hi" # <-- local assignment
    message("Set value at position ", x, " to ", mylist[[ x ]]) # local
    myf(x-1) # <-- recursive call
    message("Value at position ", x-1, " is ", mylist[[ x-1 ]]) # local
    assign('mylist', mylist, envir = parent.frame())  # <-- assign to mylist in parent environment
    tmp <- get('mylist', envir = parent.frame())
    message('mylist in parent envirnonment: ')
    print(tmp)
  }
}

myf(1)
mylist
myf(2)
mylist
myf(3)
mylist
```

See also: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html

Comment: Thank you -- does  the assignment copy the *entire* list every time? I.e. instead of writing one value (the new one), `length(mylist)` many write operations happen?

Comment: `assign('mylist', mylist, envir = parent.frame())` overwrites the entire copy of `mylist` in the parent environment with the one from the local environment. If you want to maintain the state of the copy in the parent environment, you should use `mylist <- get('mylist', envir = parent.frame())` to bring the modified `mylist` from parent envir into local, modify that copy and then assign it back to the parent environment.