# How to create multiple plots, stored in a list, and save as a PDF?

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop, ggplot2

I got a problem with my loop. I got a data frame with 25 columns and 302 rows. I want to make plots using *ggplot* of column 1 and 2, column 1 and 3, 1 and 4, etc.

When I execute the code, all plots that are made are x=column 1 and y=column 25. This is the code I used, mind, I am very new to R. So a lot could be better I guess ;-)

What am I doing wrong? Maybe it is very obvious.

```
#make plots with for loop, store the plots in a list
i <-2
list_plots <- list()
for (i in 2:ncol(plate1)) {

#plot A1
p <-  ggplot(plate1, aes(x=plate1[,1], y=plate1[,i])) + geom_point(col="steelblue", size=1) + 
                  geom_line(col="steelblue", size=1) + 
                  ggtitle(A1) + xlab("Time (h)") + ylab("pH") + 
                  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(xmin, xmax), breaks=seq(xmin, xmax, xbreak)) +
                  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(ymin, ymax), breaks=seq(ymin, ymax, ybreak))
print(i)
list_plots[[i]] <- p

}

#Arrange and save
arrange <- ggarrange(list_plots[[2]], list_plots[[3]], list_plots[[4]], list_plots[[5]], list_plots[[6]], 
                 list_plots[[7]], list_plots[[8]], list_plots[[9]], list_plots[[10]], list_plots[[11]], 
                 list_plots[[12]], list_plots[[13]], list_plots[[14]], list_plots[[15]],  

                 list_plots[[16]], 
                 list_plots[[17]], list_plots[[18]], list_plots[[19]], list_plots[[20]], 
                 list_plots[[21]], 
                 list_plots[[22]], list_plots[[23]], list_plots[[24]], list_plots[[25]], 
                  ncol = 2, nrow = 3)

#save file in current working directory
ggexport(
arrange,
plotlist = NULL,
filename = "whole plate2.pdf")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Update:

The "easiest" solution would be creating a data.frame for plotting, instead of referencing to `i` inside of `aes`;

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

plate1 <- iris[,-ncol(iris)] ## Creating dummy data using iris dataset
list_plots <- list()

for (i in 2:ncol(plate1)) {
  print(i)
  plot_data <- data.frame(x = plate1[,1], y = plate1[,i])
  p <-  ggplot(plot_data, aes(x, y)) + 
      geom_point(col="steelblue", size=1) + 
      geom_line(col="steelblue", size=1) + 
      ggtitle(i) + xlab("Time (h)") + ylab("pH")
  list_plots[[i-1]] <- p
}
#> [1] 2
#> [1] 3
#> [1] 4

plots_arrange <- ggarrange(list_plots[[1]], list_plots[[3]], list_plots[[2]],
                           ncol = 2, nrow = 3)

plots_arrange
```

[image]

---

We can use `lapply` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

plate1 <- iris[,-ncol(iris)] ## Creating dummy data using iris dataset

lapply(2:ncol(plate1), function(i){
        ggplot(plate1, aes(x=plate1[[1]], y=plate1[[i]])) + 
          geom_point(col="steelblue", size=1) + 
          geom_line(col="steelblue", size=1) + 
          ggtitle(i) + xlab("Time (h)") + ylab("pH")}) -> list_plots

plots_arrange <- ggarrange(list_plots[[1]], list_plots[[3]], list_plots[[2]],
                     ncol = 2, nrow = 3)

plots_arrange
```

[image]

But I am not sure why do you need to loop through the columns, since you can simply reshape your data and use facets.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

plate1 <- iris[,-ncol(iris)] ## Creating dummy data using iris dataset

plate1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-1) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x=.[[1]], y=value)) + 
  geom_point(col="steelblue", size=1) + 
  geom_line(col="steelblue", size=1) + 
  facet_wrap(~name, ncol = 2, scales = "free") +
  xlab("Time (h)") + ylab("pH")
```

[image]

---

**But why does the for-loop not work?** You should read about local and global scope in R: [Global and local variables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904124/global-and-local-variables-in-r)

If we have to stick to a for-loop, then this works:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

plate1 <- iris[,-ncol(iris)] ## Creating dummy data using iris dataset
list_plots <- list()

for (i in 2:ncol(plate1)) {
  print(i)
  list_plots[[i-1]] <- local({
    i <- i ## this is crucial, assigning i from outer scope to local
    p <-  ggplot(plate1, aes(x=plate1[,1], y=plate1[,i])) + 
      geom_point(col="steelblue", size=1) + 
      geom_line(col="steelblue", size=1) + 
      ggtitle(i) + xlab("Time (h)") + ylab("pH")
    print(p)
  }
  )
}

    #> [1] 2

    #> [1] 3

    #> [1] 4
  
plots_arrange <- ggarrange(list_plots[[1]], list_plots[[3]], list_plots[[2]],
                           ncol = 2, nrow = 3)

plots_arrange
```

[image]