Why do R attributes set within a function disappear after returning?
As shown below, I am trying to assign an attribute to the global variable inside the function.
The attribute is retained inside the function, but disappears after return.
Why is this happening?
foo <- "foo"
(function () {
  attr(foo, "qux") <- "quo"
  print(attr(foo, "qux")) # => "quo"
})()
print(attr(foo, "qux")) # => NULL

print(R.version$version.string) # => "R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21)"


Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904124/global-and-local-variables-in-r

It's dangerous to mess with global variables inside a function (see https://luzkan.github.io/smells/global-data), but you could do it by adding foo <<- foo after the attr() line. I think a better practice would be to make a function that changes attributes and then put a variable through it, assigning the output to the variable. e.g. quxr <- function(f) {attr(f, "qux") <- "quo"; f};   foo <- quxr(foo)

@JonSpring Thanks to an important insight you gave me, I got what happened in the code before Konrad posted the complete answer. I basically agree to the idea avoiding to mutate the global variables while occasionally we need to resort it.

You have two objects named foo here: one declared in the global environment, and one that you are creating inside your anonymous function via assignment.
The assignment is happening when you are calling the attr<- replacement function. Calls of the form f(x, ...) <- y are equivalent to the following:
`*tmp*` <- x
x <- `f<-`(`*tmp*`, ..., value = y)
rm(`*tmp*`)

As you can see, this is creating a new variable x in the local scope. The same is true in your code: it’s the same as if you had written:
`*tmp*` <- foo
foo <- `attr<-`(`*tmp*`, "qux", value = "quo")
rm(`*tmp*`)

The global object foo is never modified. If you want the changes to be visible globally, return the modified object (and, for good measure, you might want to pass the global object as an argument, too):
foo <- "foo"

f <- function (foo) {
  attr(foo, "qux") <- "quo"
  print(attr(foo, "qux")) # => "quo"
  foo
}

foo <- f(foo)
attr(foo, "qux") # => "quo"


Your answer as well as the document you linked is exactly what I looked for!
This behavior looks curious at first glance for one familiar with other programming languages like JS. It is because attr(foo, "qux") <- looks like it refers to the foo variable but does not assign anything to it.
But once I understand the replacement function, it is even an art of the language design.
